# Javascript check to see if an event has already been fired or clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that needs to fire when I click on a chevron tab.  However I only need that function to fire that first time we load the page.  How can I prevent it form firing every time the tab is clicked?

```
    $('#navi a').bind('click',function(e){
        var $this   = $(this);
        var prevButton  = current;
        $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');

        if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'tab2')
        {
            //fire function only once
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need only **part** of your event handler to run once :

```
$("div").on("click",function(){
    if (!$(this).data("fired")) {
        console.log("Running once");
        $(this).data("fired",true);
    }

    console.log("Things as usual");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kL34g/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binding instead. This will attach it to fire on the first click and remove itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var isalreadyclicked=false;
  $('#navi a').bind('click',function(e){
    var $this   = $(this);
    var prevButton  = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');

    if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'tab2')
    {
    if(!isalreadyclicked){
        //fire function only once
    isalreadyclicked=true;
    }
    }

  });
```

Comment: I have other stuff in that click that need to happen every time....its just that one function that only needs the first time...I dont want to do the one on every other thing

Comment: @DocHoliday: It's acceptable to use `$('#navi a').one(function(){ /* one-time code */ }).click(function(){ /* always code */ });`...